# Angular - How can I cancel $interval when state changes?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ngRoute. There is an $interval on `dashboardController`, How can I cancel it after leaving `dashboard` page? I tried to listen to `$destroy`. But it seems this event fires when I enter `dashboard` page. `$routeChangeSuccess` also doesn't work.

route:

```
    .when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashboardController',
    })
    .when('/applications', {
        templateUrl: 'applications.html',
        controller: 'appController',
    })
```

dashboardController:

```
var update = $interval(function() {
  //.....
},1000)

$scope.$watch('$destroy', function(e) {
  $interval.cancel(update);
})
```

Comment: Can you give us a high level overview of why you need to cancel the interval?  There might be a better solution we could offer up.

Comment: I'm using $interval to keep sending ajax requests to update some data on `dashboard` and some other pages. Obviously I don't want to keep sending all the requests when I'm only using a part of them.

Comment: Why wouldn't `$destroy` work for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah I missed it the first time!  You have `$scope.$watch` but it should be `$on`

The following code will cancel your interval on `$destroy`, which gets called when your route changes.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(e) {
  $interval.cancel(update);
});
```

Comment: Oh I didn't notice my syntax...Thank you Nix